# SQL combining multiple select statements into a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query which gets the total outstanding invoices and removed the total payments and credit notes to get the outstanding balance.

```
declare @tInv decimal(19, 2)
declare @tCrn decimal(19, 2)
declare @tPay decimal(19, 2)

set @tInv = 
(
SELECT SUM(ST_Unallocated) from Transactions where ST_COPYCUST = 'LOEH001' and ST_TRANTYPE = 'INV'
)
set @tCrn =
(
    SELECT SUM(ST_Unallocated) from Transactions where ST_COPYCUST = 'LOEH001' and ST_TRANTYPE = 'CRN'
)

set @tPay = 
(
SELECT SUM(ST_Unallocated) from Transactions where ST_COPYCUST = 'LOEH001' and ST_TRANTYPE = 'PAY'
)

declare @currBal decimal(19, 2)
set @currBal =
(
SELECT @tInv - @tPay - @tCrn
)
select @currBal
```

I want to combine the above query with the below query to show the total outstanding balance for each customer -

```
select 
    c.AccountNumber, 
    c.CustomerID, 
    c.FullName, 
    ct.Description as 'CustomerTypeDesc', 
    c.TelNumber, 
    c.EmailAddress 
from Customers c
inner join CustomerTypes ct on c.CustomerType = ct.TypeID
left join Transactions t on c.AccountNumber = ST_COPYCUST
where c.StatusID = 0 or c.StatusID = 1
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query. I have made a few assumptions and have removed the join on the `Transactions` table from your primary query as I think this is surplus to requirements. The beauty of using these inline queries is that you can return more than one customer if required (by removing the filter on c.AccountNumber):

```
SELECT
  c.AccountNumber
, c.CustomerID
, c.FullName
, ct.Description as 'CustomerTypeDesc'
, c.TelNumber
, c.EmailAddress
, (SELECT SUM(ST_Unallocated) from Transactions where ST_COPYCUST = c.AccountNumber and ST_TRANTYPE = 'INV') -
  (SELECT SUM(ST_Unallocated) from Transactions where ST_COPYCUST = c.AccountNumber and ST_TRANTYPE = 'CRN') -
 (SELECT SUM(ST_Unallocated) from Transactions where ST_COPYCUST = c.AccountNumber and ST_TRANTYPE = 'PAY') AS BalanceToPay
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN CustomerTypes ct on c.CustomerType = ct.TypeID
WHERE c.StatusID IN (0,1) AND c.AccountNumber = ST_COPYCUST
```

Comment: This seems to work, however I need a single column in addition to the individual transaction columns which shows tInv - tCRN - tPAY. Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Can't the 3 selects from transactions could be converted into one?

Comment: @MattBaughan ok updated - a simple subtraction really, this query could be optimised further I think with time although for your needs it may perform well enough

Answer (score 0):

Hope didn't broke it, should be faster than with subqueries:

```
SELECT
 c.AccountNumber
, c.CustomerID
, c.FullName
, ct.Description as 'CustomerTypeDesc'
, c.TelNumber
, c.EmailAddress
, SUM(CASE WHEN ST_TRANTYPE = 'INV' THEN t.ST_Unallocated ELSE 0 END) AS tInv
, SUM(CASE WHEN ST_TRANTYPE = 'CRN' THEN t.ST_Unallocated ELSE 0 END) AS tCRN
, SUM(CASE WHEN ST_TRANTYPE = 'PAY' THEN t.ST_Unallocated ELSE 0 END) AS tPAY
, SUM(CASE WHEN ST_TRANTYPE = 'INV' THEN t.ST_Unallocated ELSE 0 END) - 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ST_TRANTYPE = 'PAY' THEN t.ST_Unallocated ELSE 0 END) -
    SUM(CASE WHEN ST_TRANTYPE = 'CRN' THEN t.ST_Unallocated ELSE 0 END) as currBal
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN CustomerTypes ct on c.CustomerType = ct.TypeID
LEFT JOIN Transactions t on c.AccountNumber = t.ST_COPYCUST
WHERE c.StatusID = 0 or c.StatusID = 1 AND  c.AccountNumber = ST_COPYCUST
GROUP BY  c.AccountNumber
, c.CustomerID
, c.FullName
, ct.Description
, c.TelNumber
, c.EmailAddress
```